# Gradle owasp plugin does not see CVE-2022-42889

Tags: java, spring, gradle, owasp, apache-commons-text

I have a `build.gradle` file with the following plugins and dependencies

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'org.owasp.dependencycheck' version '7.3.0',
    ...
}

ext {
    ...
    okHttpVersion = '4.9.3'
    ...
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(
            ...
            //misc
            'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.16.3',
            'org.everit.json:org.everit.json.schema:1.5.1',
            'com.github.therapi:therapi-runtime-javadoc:0.13.0',
            'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9.0',  //this is the vulnerability
            "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpVersion",
            "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:$okHttpVersion",
            ...
    )
    ...
}
```

When I run `./gradlew dependencyCheckAnalyze` in the report I cannot see the anything about `'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9.0'`

I have tried to execute `./gradlew dependencyCheckPurge` then `./gradlew dependencyCheckUpadte` followd by `./gradlew dependencyCheckAnalyze`, however the report outputs are same

Comment: A registered [question](https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/5012) on GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the plugin did not recognise MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH pattern, rather MAJOR.MINOR. Therefore `1.9.0` was not visible
On top of it in maven repository there are no [`1.9.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text) anymore

Putting `1.9` fixed the report results

However I reckon it is plugin issue

`UPDATED 07.11.2022`:

`1.9.0` never existed